# Fetch data using date function

Tags: javascript, erp

I want to fetch data after 19/11/2019.I have tried below code but still not working.

```
frappe.ui.form.on("Employee",    
{
    "reports_to" : function(frm) 
     {        
        if (row.date >= 19-11-2019)       
        {       
            row.reports_to = frm.doc.reports_to;

            row.reports_to_name = frm.doc.reports_to_name;
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Does it throw an error?  try using YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Did you mean to compare row.date to the result of 19 minus 11 minus 2019?

Comment: The fix will depend on how the date is represented in your data.  It could be seconds since epoch UTC, or could be a string in YYYY-MM-DD format, or a string in YYYYMMDD format, for example.

Comment: I want to fetch data from 19th nov 2019. Its not even giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

I think before you need to set a date comparison condition. You have to convert both dates in same format. It will help you to get the proper results.

```
var date = new Date(y,m,d);

mydate=new Date('2019-11-19');
console.log(date);
console.log(mydate);
```

Comment: Jaydeep Charadva still no output.

Comment: have you checked that your if condition is correct or not? Make sure that after your mentioned date records are available.

Comment: That's what I am asking, what condition can be given?? Current condition is not working.

Comment: check console.log(row.date) before if condition. what is the output of that?

Comment: No output yet. I guess the condition is not working. Need to try some other condition

Comment: I think as per your mentioned function, row.date variable is wrong. If any date is comming in that variable then it should be print on console.
by use of console.log(row.date)